# Acessa controller de um outro projeto na mesma solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pessoal eu eu tenho 3 projetos na mesma solution:
KnockDocWeb, KanoDockModels e KnodockApi como mostra a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu compilo o projeto ele inicia o KanoDockWeb, porém eu quero Acessar uma Controller que esta no KanoDocApi  pelo KanoDockWeb.

Eu quero acessar uma controller chamada UsuarioApiController e o método Login;

Eu quero saber, na URL como eu acesso aquela controller?

Eu já tentei:

```
localhost:18459/UsuarioApi/Login
localhost:18459/api/UsuarioApi/Login
localhost:18459 /KnockDocApi/UsuarioApi/Login
```

Nenhum eu obtive êxito.

Mais uma coisa:

Quando eu dou um brakpoint em qualquer controller de KnockDocApi eu tenho a seguinte mensagem: The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document.

Só ressaltando que o KanoDockApi é um projeto do tipo Web Api

Por favor, alguém me ajuda???

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Um projeto faz `using` do outro? Como você está fazendo com o Service Locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robson, você está trabalhando com 2 projetos do tipo Web Application, para rodar, eles precisariam estar publicados (num servidor web ou numa web server virtual como está fazendo aí). 
O que você está querendo fazer é o mesmo que 2 websites se comunicarem e trocarem informação.
Para conseguir rodar os 2, você teria que abrir uma porta para cada aplicação. Porém, mesmo assim não seria possível fazer essas chamadas, somente independentes. Suas tentativas não funcionam pois o KnockDocWeb está rodando na porta 18459, e não o KnockDocApi.
Te aconselho a criar um novo projeto do tipo Class Library que conterá a lógica desta controller que você está precisando chamar. Assim, ela pode ser compartilhada em ambos web sites.